# Приоритет вызовов события jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется: `<div><span>x</span></div>`
Событие **onclick** навешано на **div**, а так же событие onclick на **span**.
Соответственно при клике на span, первым вызывается событие по div. 
Как это избежать?

Answer (score 1):

[`stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: тогда и на нативный [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) нужно добавить. а то как-то маловат ответ :-) А вообще можно было еще добавить, что в разных браузерах могут быть разные направления

Comment: @Grundy у автора в тегах jQuery.

Comment: у него и `javascript` в тегах :-)

Comment: @Grundy интерпретация тегов не маловажный навык, который позволяет более точно давать ответ на вопрос :)

Comment: :-D судя по тому, что ответ не помечен как принятый - что-то пошло не так

Comment: @Grundy у тс все вопросы не помечены, будьте внимательней ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32153/discussion-between-grundy-and-lampa).